# ODBC - No connection host specified

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, odbc, containers, pyodbc

I am testing a simple python script in an Openshift container. The goal is to connect to an Exasol database and perform a test query.
I connect using SQLAlchemy's engine. The problem is that this works only if I specify the server's URL. Instead, if I use the dns, it doesn't work.

When trying to connect, I get the following error message: "sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('SO085', u'[SO085] [unixODBC][EXASOL][EXASolution driver]No connection host specified. (-5) (SQLDriverConnect)')"

The code is the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

dsn="pa_eu_dsn"
creds="user:pwd"
details = "exa+pyodbc://"
conn_string = details + creds + "@" + dsn

# THIS ENGINE DOESN'T WORK
engine = create_engine(conn_string, isolation_level='READ_COMMITTED')

# THIS WORKS
# engine = create_engine("exa+pyodbc://user:pwd@10.111.144.90..92:8563/SYS?CONNECTIONLCALL=en_US.UTF-8&driver=Exasol")


#print("tables: ", engine.table_names())

connection = engine.connect()
```

The same code, if executed on a regular virtual machine, works fine with both engines. My guess is that this is due to a wrong configuration/location of odbc.ini in the container.

Therefore, I tried executing the following:

```
sources = pyodbc.dataSources()   
print("sources: ", sources)
```

When executed in the container, this command returns empty.

My odbc settings for the container are the same as for the VM, and they are as follows:

```
sh-4.2$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: .odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage       = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1
# Exasol drivers
[Exasol]
Driver = /EXASOL_ODBC-6.0.8/lib/linux/x86_64/libexaodbc-uo2214lv2.so
Threading = 2
```

/.odbc.ini:

```
[pa_eu_dsn]
DRIVER = Exasol
EXAHOST = 10.111.144.90..92:8563
CONNECTIONLCALL = en_US.utf-8
```

Does anybody know what could I be missing? Maybe, during the container configuration (done through a Dockerfile) should I specify something more regarding the odbc.ini file?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: If you really have your DSN defined in `/.odbc.ini` then perhaps try moving that file to `~/.odbc.ini` or putting your DSN definition in `/etc/odbc.ini`.

Comment: Hello @GordThompson, I confirm that it actually works if I put the dsn definition in /etc/odbc.ini. This is weird and unexpected. I thought the dsn definitions where in the right place, since misspelling the dsn name in the script caused a "Data source name not found" error, which didn't occur with the right spelling. Anyways, now it works. Thank you for your help!